# Java Extending Final Classes

Tags: java, oop

I would like to override a 3rd party, open-source final class's non-final method.

```
final class A 
{
    void put(obj a)
    {...}

    obj get()
    {...}
}
```

Please tell me how to override the `get()` and `put()` methods, yet still retain the other behaviour and functionality of this class.

Comment: Look if `A` is implementing some interface, which is actually used. In this case you are lucky: you can create `A1` including `A` as a member and reimplement all interface methods.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's open source: fork it, and make the class non-final.

You won't be able to extend it without making it non-final.

Comment: thanks, Jon. what's 'fork' mean? Copy and paste the code, and then remove "final," and then re-write the get and put methods?

Comment: @Kevin: Fork as in "create your own version". Whether you make that public or not is your own call. You could either make the class non-final and extend it, or potentially just change the behaviour of `get` / `put` yourself. Of course the downside is that every time you want to get a new version of the library, you'll have to make your change again...

Comment: is this option superior to the wrapper approach? If so, please tell me why. I'm curious architecturally.

Comment: @Kevin: Sometimes inheritance appropriate, other times composition/delegation is appropriate. There are various aspects to the decision, including whether identity is important. Personally I prefer composition/delegation in general, but we can't possibly know whether that's appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 4):

If your class has a defined interface in which put and get methods are defined then You may want to try to proxy the class.

The easiest way is to create something like this:

```
public interface CommonInterface {

void put(); Object get();

}

final class A implements CommonInterface
{

void put(obj a)
{...}
obj get()
{...}

}

public class ProxyToA implements CommonInterface{

   private A a;

  void put(Object a){
   // your override functionality

  } 

    Object get(){
       // same here
    }

   void otherAStuff(){
        a.otherAStuff();
   }

}
```

And then just use CommonInterface and proxy your object. Or you can use JDK proxies, javassist, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can't extend `final` class. Per Java spec.

Comment: @Phlip: if you need to override something, use interfaces, not classes, in your design hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try to find out *why* the class is final. If you are able to convince yourself it is ok to do that, another options is to use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) to just change the behavior of thse two methods.

**AspectJ** allows you to modify behavior of specific methods. It can do this even for `private` methods -- security constraints permitting -- and access and assign private fields of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot override the methods because you cannot extend the class. What are you planning to do with the get and put methods by overriding? If you are looking add some functionality to those methods, you can create another class which wraps around this class.